# Set close icon on right side of Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Twitter-Bootstrap Modal currently, and I need to close an icon on the right-hand side of the header. I tried to use CSS to set it, but it didn't work.

The code:

```
<div class="modal-content json-modal-body" id="full-width" ng-controller="projectdetailsController" close="CloseModal()">
    <div class="modal-header modal-header-confirm">
        <h4 class="modal-title ng-binding">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left"></span>{{modalOptions.headerText}}
            <a title="Close"><i ng-click="CloseModal()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-arrow-right"></i></a> 
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> 
         <pre class="Modal-pre" ng-bind-html="modalOptions.bodyText"></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS that I tried to use:

```
 .icon-arrow-right {
  float: right;
  }
```

Comment: where is `.icon-arrow-right` ?

Comment: <a title="Close"><i ng-click="CloseModal()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-arrow-right"></i></a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="modal-content json-modal-body" id="full-width" ng-controller="projectdetailsController" close="CloseModal()">
<div class="modal-header modal-header-confirm">
    <h4 class="modal-title ng-binding">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left"></span>{{modalOptions.headerText}}
        <a title="Close"><i ng-click="CloseModal()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-arrow-right pull-right"></i></a> 
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body"> 
     <pre class="Modal-pre" ng-bind-html="modalOptions.bodyText"></pre>
</div>
</div>
```

Just add a pull-right to the class to make the element appear right. The above code should work

Comment: can you tell me how can i close the Modal when the close icon is clicked ?

Comment: you could add data-dismiss="modal" to your arrow icon to close the modal when clicked.